# llvm coredump at llvm::Value::getContext()

Tags: clang, llvm

```
* thread #1: tid = 26059, 0x00007f6324bc91c3 llvmjit.so`llvm::Value::getContext() const + 3, name = 'postgres', stop reason = invalid address (fault address: 0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007f6324bc91c3 llvmjit.so`llvm::Value::getContext() const + 3
    frame #1: 0x00007f6324bca7ca llvmjit.so`llvm::Value::setNameImpl(llvm::Twine const&) + 26
    frame #2: 0x00007f6324bcaa59 llvmjit.so`llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&) + 9
    frame #3: 0x00007f6324adb928 llvmjit.so`LLVMBuildExtractValue + 456
```

source code: use llvm-c api to call intrinsic function

```
        v_fn = LLVMGetNamedFunction(mod, "llvm.sadd.with.overflow.i64");
        if (!v_fn)
        {
            LLVMTypeRef param_types[2];
            LLVMTypeRef v_fn_type;

            param_types[0] = LLVMInt64Type();
            param_types[1] = LLVMInt64Type();

            v_fn_type = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt64Type(), param_types, lengthof(param_types), 0);
            v_fn = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "llvm.sadd.with.overflow.i64", v_fn_type);
        }

        params[0] = l_int64_const(1);
        params[1] = l_int64_const(1);

        v_res = LLVMBuildCall(b, v_fn,
                              params, lengthof(params), "");

        v_flag = LLVMBuildExtractValue(b, v_res, 1, "");
        v_flag = LLVMBuildIsNotNull(b, v_flag, "");
```

when i use LLVMBuildExtractValue to get result from intrinsic llvm.sadd.with.overflow.i64, got stack above.
i can only get that context is 0x0. but what cause this. Anyone can help pls?

Comment: Sounds like a routine mistake, calling llvm::verifyModule() is likely to point out precisely where.

Comment: ok, now i have compiled llvm in debug mode so i can print lots of detailed llvm functions, which helps a lot. I will try your advice if still get such message later. thanks